# Finding linear relationship between A, C using known linear relationships of A, B and B, C?

Tags: regression, linear

I have three tests A, B, C.

I have many samples of students who have taken tests A and B and, using linear regression, have found a relationship between test scores of A and B.
Similarly, I have many samples of students who have taken tests B and C and found a linear relationship there as well.

However, I have very few samples of students who have taken A and C or all three tests.

Can I use my knowledge of students who have taken A and B, and who have taken B and C to predict a relationship between scores of tests A and C?